# For loop inside the cursor in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a package :

```
create or replace package body package_name
as 
procedure 
update_dte
cursor cur_variable is 
select person_id, eff_start_date, eff_end_date from tab_abc;

begin

open cursor cur_variable;
loop
num_count := cur_variable%ROWCOUNT;

for i in 1..num_count
loop
fetch cursor cur_variable
into l_person_id, l_eff_start_date, l_eff_end_date;

update tab_abc
set l_eff_start_date='31-dec-4712'
where person_id=l_person_id;
end loop;
end loop;
close cur_variable;

end;
end;
/
```

This query where i have used for loop inside cursor loop is going into endless loop. Basically i want to travel through the cursor till its row count so that no iteration is missed for update.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor and a for loop in the first place? Seems unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't working as you expect because a) you are missing the exit clause from your outer loop, b) until you have fetched at least row, the %ROWCOUNT will return 0 (and even if it had fetched a row, if you're expecting it to return the number of rows in the cursor, then you're sadly mistaken - we'll only know the number of rows returned by the cursor once we've finished fetching all the rows from the cursor), c) with `l_eff_start_date = '31-dec-4712'` you are trying to set a variable as part of an update statement - this doesn't make sense! - and d) you haven't declared the l_person_id, l_eff_start_date, l_eff_end_date or num_count variables.

You have some options - first off, here is what your code should look like - you don't need that outer loop at all:

```
create or replace package body package_name
as 
  procedure update_dte
  is

    cursor cur_variable is 
    select person_id, eff_start_date, eff_end_date
    from   tab_abc;

  begin
    open cursor cur_variable;
    loop
      fetch cursor cur_variable
      into l_person_id, l_eff_start_date, l_eff_end_date;

      exit when cur_variable%notfound;

      update tab_abc
      set    start_date = to_date('31-12-4712', 'dd-mm-yyyy') -- assuming start_date is of DATE datatype;
      where  person_id=l_person_id;
    end loop;

    close cur_variable;

  end update_dte;
end package_name;
/
```

However, there's an easier way of looping through a cursor, where you don't have to worry about creating a variable to return values into, opening or closing the cursor or fetching the records - the cursor-for-loop will handle all this for you:

```
create or replace package body package_name
as 
  procedure update_dte
  is

    cursor cur_variable is 
    select person_id, eff_start_date, eff_end_date
    from   tab_abc;

  begin
    for rec in cur_variable;
    loop
      update tab_abc
      set    start_date = to_date('31-12-4712', 'dd-mm-yyyy') -- assuming start_date is of DATE datatype;
      where  person_id=l_person_id;
    end loop;
  end update_dte;
end package_name;
/
```

However, far better and more performant is to use a single update statement to do the work in one fell swoop, rather than row-by-row. In your case, you didn't even need the cursor to loop through, since you're updating all the rows in tab_abc, so your update becomes simply:

```
create or replace package body package_name
as 
  procedure update_dte
  is
  begin
    update tab_abc
    set    start_date = to_date('31-12-4712', 'dd-mm-yyyy'); -- assuming start_date is of DATE datatype;
  end update_dte;
end package_name;
/
```

In all three cases, I've assumed that you were trying to update the start_date column (and that it's of DATE datatype). If that isn't the case, you need to update your question to include more details on what you're trying to do with this procedure. Is it a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is obvious: You don't have an exit condition. Also, I don't quite see why you need two loops. Then only one you need is the inner loop.

Add an exit condition (don't recall the exact syntax though) something like:

```
EXIT WHEN cur_variable%NOT_FOUND ;
```

This should be immediately after the `FETCH`.

By the way, you don't need to check the number of records. Just loop (forever) and exit when no more results returned from the `FETCH`.

Comment: Actually, the issue is there isn't an exit statement in the outer loop - the cursor will never be fetched from, since `num_count := cur_variable%ROWCOUNT;` will always be 0.

Comment: That is why I wrote you to remove the counter in the loop and only check if the cursor returns an END-OF-DATA condition to exit the loop (which, by the way, I also mentioned that you are missing in your code).

Comment: I'm not the OP. But I take your point; I had missed the fact that the missing exit statement from your first sentence is not the same as your example exit statement; my bad - sorry!

Comment: No problem. Don't worry.